# Final undergraduate project "Load Balancing Server"?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, load-balancing, distributed

this year i'll start my final undegraduate project, basically i'll implement a simple server-based load balancer for Linux. The intention is to make it application independent (Web server, FTP server, Email Server, etc) at OSI Layer 4 (TCP). The load balancer needs to listen all ports and forward the packages to the configured real servers, to his respective requested port  (following an algorithm like round-robin).

Another intention is to make this Load Balancer as a Kernel Module (Like LVS, a native load balancer for Linux), and make another user-space administrative application to make configuration.

But i'm with a lot of doubts, 
The only way to do this load balancer this is with a Kernel Module? It can't be only an user-space program? 
It can't be at Layer 3 (IP)? Where I acess it the IP packets and process all the logic?

Please, help me with these doubts, it's important to guide me in the start of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be quite technical as you are talking about implementing a kernel module. You said "forward the packages" at TCP layer. But then you said "listen to all ports and forward the packages". So in order to implement this first you need to know the differences:

- "forward the **packages**" At TCP level, means that the Linux should be able to  intercept and forward packages (basically doing NAT) and the only way to accomplish this is using the [netfilters](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html) just like `iptables` and LVS does (it doesn't **listen** to any port). `iptables` is an application that allows you to configure the tables provided by the Linux kernel firewall, which uses the netfilter's hooks. So, yes, it can't be a user-space program unless you mean a front-end that uses `iptables` for configuring NAT, but I don't think this is the point.
- "listen to all ports and forward the packages" means that your load balancer will work at Application Layer 4 and probably what you want is a TCP Proxy. TCP Proxy applications runs on user-space and you can implement it to listen to a set of ports, then forward what comes in/back to/from another, like [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) and [Balance](https://www.inlab.de/balance.html).

[Balance](https://www.inlab.de/balance.html) is very simple and open source so it is a good start point.

The [l3dsr](https://github.com/yahoo/l3dsr) and [lnlb](http://lnlb.sourceforge.net/) are good references too.

Besides layer 4 and layer 7, there are network load balance at layer 2 (link aggregation, port aggregation, etherchannel or gigabit etherchannel port bundling), and layer 3 like [Cisco Express Forwarding](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/switch/configuration/guide/fswtch_c/xcfcef.html)

EDIT: [Nftables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nftables) works different. `nftables` is the userspace part of a new general-purpose in-kernel packet classification engine. "`nftables` adds a simple virtual machine into the Linux kernel, which is able inspect a network packet and make decisions on how that packet should be handled".

Comment: Wow, a lot of information. Thank you man!

Let me see if a understand you allright, [1] to develop at kernel-space I will work with netfilters API, at Layer 3 (it just works with IP packets?). [2] If i want to develop at user-space, i can work at Layer 4, for example, making a front-end to iptables (a TCP Proxy service).

I dont know yet, but i think an Layer 3 balancer is a best approach, because i'll not depend on applications/ports. Just will handle the IP packets.

Comment: Last doubt, working with netfilters and kernel-module programming will be heavy to an undergraduate student? I don't have experience with kernel-module programming, but i am confortable with linux and networking, and i will propose a very simple Load Balancer...

Comment: For some reason I haven't received your comment notification. But let me answer: 1: Yes you will use netfilters hooks. 2: Making a front-end to iptables does not means that your application works at "layer 4", it just means that you use some resources of SO at user-level, that's all. If you want to develop at layer 4, then you should implement using netfilter's hooks or use any library that end up using it anyway (like Wireshark does). It is just a matter of what you want to accomplish. Layer 3 may not be necessarily better... all of them have its uses.

Comment: If I consider the level of your questions (no offense) I could say that will be *very* challenging for you to implement using netfilter's hooks. If your main goal is to learn about kernel development and you have time for a long project, it may worth, but I strongly suggest you to begin with user-level applications, TCP-Proxys, like balancer. Besides your network and linux-administrator experience, you should be very comfortable with advanced C development and kernel structures too.